# talend tMap logic vs SQL logic - performance

Tags: sql, performance, talend, query-performance

My scenario is this:  I have two fields(ref1, ref2)  in the table where I can get the values I need depending on another field (factor_column) value.  This can be achieved in two ways, but I'm not sure which would be more efficient?

1) using SELECT case when factor_column = Y then ref1...

2) normal SELECT ref1, ref2 etc.  And using an expression in talend component tMap: (factor_column.equals("Y")? ref1: ref2)

My talend job flow is something like:
tOracleInput -> tMap - tOutput

Is it better to put the logic on SELECT clause on tOracleInput or to put on tMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the `tOracleInput` : The logic will be excuted with the whole query, in the DBMS via JDBC connection
- In the `tMap` : The logic will be executed in the JVM.

Generally, it will be faster to use the DBMS rather then the ETL and job design will be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

- If you use the SELECT and do the processing in the database, huge datasets will be processed outside of the ETL/ELT job which can be very helpful
- If you use an expression, the whole dataset will be loaded into Talend and processed. Depending on the dataset, you might not have enough RAM or Heap to complete your request (think also growing datasets over time)

So this depends on your data size.